# Laravel - using a class in the same folder

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller, laravel-4

I am looking to have a separate class to handle the validation of a new user.

Folder structure is:

```
| app
  | Website
    | UserCreator
       - UserCreator.php
       - UserValidation.php
```

In my UserCreator file I am trying to use a method in the UserValidation class like this:

```
public function createUser($input)
{
    UserValidation::validate($input);
}
```

However I am getting this:

```
Class 'Website\UserCreator\UserValidation' not found
```

This is the validation class:

```
<?php
```

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator as Validator;

```
class userValidation {

  public static $rules = array(
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'email_address' => 'unique:users'
  );

  public static $messages = [
  ];

  /**
   * validate the new user input
   * @param  $input
  */
  public function validate($input) {
    // validate
  }

}
```

Do I need to instantiate a class like this? As I do in my controller?

My controller is:

```
Use Website\UserCreator\UserCreator as UserCreator;

class UserCreatorController extends BaseController
{

  protected $userCreator;

  public function __construct(UserCreator $userCreator){
    $this->userCreator = $userCreator;
  }

  public function addNewUser() {
    return $this->userCreator->createUser($input);
  }


}
```

Because the classes are in the same folder, I didnt think I needed to namespace the validation one / define a use for it in the UserCreator?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What does your `UserValidation` file look like?

Comment: @KevinNagurski just edited the question to show it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the namespace... PHP doesn't care what directory your file is in, so make sure you specify `namespace Website\UserCreator;`. If that does't work, what's your autoloader like?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :-)